# ASP.NET MVC on IIS 6 problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

I am trying to get MVC to work on IIS6 and am having issues.

I went through the steps on Haaked

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

I am trying to get the  IIS6 Extension-less URLs to work

I have done the steps,and when I navigate to my site I get this error:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure "CopyLocal" is set to true on your System.Web.Mvc reference in Visual Studio.

Comment: If you haven't installed MVC on the machine I mean.

Comment: that did it!!! thank you! I didn't know that property was even there. :) good to know!
thanks!